# Processor stucks and shows slowness in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I use Nifi standalone for extraction of data from mysql and write it on S3. When i extract multiple tables in batches, 2 processors gets slowed down after processing 15-20 flowfiles of around 20-30 MB each and remains in the queue.

```
When i restart the processor, all the flow files are processed in one second and to process everything i have to do this again and again.
```

> Processors on which i am facing -  ConvertAvroToParquet and
> AttributesToJson

Comment: Increase number of threads for those processors. Increase total number of threads for nifi ..

Comment: How can i increase number of threads?

Comment: sandwich menu -> controller settings -> general

Comment: I have already set that to 100 for timer driven and event driven thread but issue is still there.

Comment: Let's focus on one of processors, Show the screenshot with bottleneck, what is the size of the file that are coming into it, what is config of the processor, how it's triggered/scheduled - please edit your question and add as much as possible to describe issue.